# How to add data beside each other in a csv file

Tags: linux, csv, sed, awk

If I have 3 csv files, and I want to merge the data all into one, but beside each other, how would I do it? For example:

Initial Merged file:

```
,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

File 1:

```
20,09/05,5694
20,09/06,3234
20,09/08,2342
```

File 2:

```
20,09/05,2341
20,09/06,2334
20,09/09,342
```

File 3:

```
20,09/05,1231
20,09/08,3452
20,09/10,2345
20,09/11,372
```

Final merged File:

```
09/05,5694,,,09/05,2341,,,09/05,1231
09/06,3234,,,09/06,2334,,,09/08,3452
09/08,2342,,,09/09,342,,,09/10,2345
,,,,,,,,09/11,372
```

Basically data from each file goes into a specific column of the merged file.
I know the awk function can be used for this, but I have no clue how to start

EDIT: Only the 2nd and 3rd Columns of each file are being printed. I was using this to print out the 2nd and 3rd columns:

```
awk -v f="${i}" -F, 'match ($0,f) { print $2","$3 }' file3.csv > d$i.csv
```

however, say for example, file1 and file2 were null in that row, the data for that row would be shifted to the left. so I came up with this to account for the shift:

```
awk -v x="${i}" -F, 'match ($0,x) { if ($2='/NULL') { print "," }; else { print $2","$3}; }' alld.csv > d$i.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU awk for ARGIND:

```
$ gawk '{ a[FNR,ARGIND]=$0; maxFnr=(FNR>maxFnr?FNR:maxFnr) }
    END {
        for (i=1;i<=maxFnr;i++) {
            for (j=1;j<ARGC;j++)
                printf "%s%s", (j==1?"":",,,"), (a[i,j]?a[i,j]:",")
            print ""
        }
    }
' file1 file2 file3
09/05,5694,,,09/05,2341,,,09/05,1231
09/06,3234,,,09/06,2334,,,09/08,3452
09/08,2342,,,09/09,342,,,09/10,2345
,,,,,,,,09/11,372
```

If you don't have GNU awk, just add an initial line that says `FNR==1{ARGIND++}`.

Commented version per request:

```
$ gawk '
    { a[FNR,ARGIND]=$0; # Store the current line in a 2-D array `a` indexed by
                        # the current line number `FNR` and file number `ARGIND`.

      maxFnr=(FNR>maxFnr?FNR:maxFnr)    # save the max FNR value
    }
    END{
        for (i=1;i<=maxFnr;i++) {  # Loop from 1 to max number of fields
                                   # seen across all files and for each:
            for (j=1;j<ARGC;j++)     # Loop from 1 to total number of files parsed and:
                printf "%s%s",         # Print 2 strings, specifically:
                   (j==1?"":",,,"),      # A field separator - empty if were printing
                                         # the first field, three commas otherwise.
                   (a[i,j]?a[i,j]:",")   # The value stored in the array if it was
                                         # present in the files, a comma otherwise.
            print ""                   # Print a newline
        }
    }
' file1 file2 file3
```

I originally was using an array `fnr[FNR]` to track the max value of FNR but IMHO that's kinda obscure and it has a flaw where if no lines have, say, a 2nd field then a loop on `for (i=1;i in fnr;i++)` in the `END` section would bail out before getting to the 3rd field.

Comment: YES!! this works, thank you.. could you please explain it though? I understand the nested loops but what do the terms mean and what exactly is happening?

Comment: I cleaned it up a bit and added a commented version. If this does what you want, remember to click the check mark next to it so others don't waste time also trying to solve it

Comment: unfortunately, I am not very well versed in this language- in general, what do the ":" and "?" mean?

Comment: That's a ternary operator, it's common in many languages. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation or just google it. `(a?b:c)` means `if (a) then b else c` and so `x=(a?b:c)` means `if (a) then x=b else x=c`.

Answer (score 3):

`paste` is done for this:

```
$ paste -d";" f1 f2 f3 | sed 's/;/,,,/g'
09/05,5694,,,09/05,2341,,,09/05,1231
09/06,3234,,,09/06,2334,,,09/08,3452
09/08,2342,,,09/09,342,,,09/10,2345
,,,,,,09/11,372
```

Note that the `paste` alone will output just one comma:

```
$ paste -d, f1 f2 f3
09/05,5694,09/05,2341,09/05,1231
09/06,3234,09/06,2334,09/08,3452
09/08,2342,09/09,342,09/10,2345
,,09/11,372
```

So to have multiple ones we can use another delimiter like `;` and then replace by `,,,` with sed:

```
$ paste -d";" f1 f2 f3 | sed 's/;/,,,/g'
09/05,5694,,,09/05,2341,,,09/05,1231
09/06,3234,,,09/06,2334,,,09/08,3452
09/08,2342,,,09/09,342,,,09/10,2345
,,,,,,09/11,372
```

Comment: Simple and cute solution, **+1**

Comment: This works.. for the most part. however when i try to incorporate it into my program it doesn't quite work (I don't know if this is a new thread or not as they are related but..) My csv has 3 columns, and i only print out the 2nd and 3rd column, I was able to implement this, however when a column from one file is null (ends earlier than the column from the next file), it messes the whole format up... I came up with this. but it gives an error:
awk -v x="${i}" -F, 'match ($0,x) { if ($2='/NULL') { print "," }; else { print $2","$3}; }' all.csv > ul$i.csv

Comment: @user2883071 please update your question with sample input so I can improve the solution. Also note this may help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16443/combine-text-files-column-wise

Answer (score 2):

Using `pr`:

```
$ pr -mts',,,' file[1-3]
09/05,5694,,,09/05,2341,,,09/05,1231
09/06,3234,,,09/06,2334,,,09/08,3452
09/08,2342,,,09/09,342,,,09/10,2345
,,,,,,09/11,372
```